# Не правильно работает структура

Tags: c++, массивы, классы

У меня есть класс, но программа вылетает после создания объекта его типа.

```
const int B = 707; /// sqrt(N)
struct Mex {
int x[N], group[B + 5];
/*
 * This struct can push and pop an element with O(1),
 * calculate MEX with O(sqrt(N))
 */

Mex() {
    fill(x, x + N, 0);
    fill(group, group + N, 0);
}


void push(int val) {
    ++x[val];
    if (x[val] == 1)
        ++group[val / B];
}


void pop(int val) {
    --x[val];
    if (x[val] == 0)
        --group[val / B];
}


int getValue() {
    for (int i = 0; i <= B + 1; ++i) {
        if (group[i] < B) {
            for (int j = i * B, end = i * (B + 1); j < end; ++j) {
                if (x[j] == 0) {
                    return j;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
};
```

Comment: Что такое `N`? Почему его не видно в коде?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну смотрите:

```
const int B = 707; /// sqrt(N)
int x[N], group[B + 5];
```

Значит, `B` ну очень сильно меньше `N`.

А заполняете вы

```
fill(group, group + N, 0);
```

куда больше, чем влазит. Портя при этом память...

P.S. Остальной функционал не смотрел. Все равно

> программа вылетает после создания объекта его типа

до него дело не доходит...

Comment: спасибо большое, не заметил

Comment: Плюс N не обьялен

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Это только фрагмент, думаю, N добавлен в другом месте (раз уж программа компилитруется)...

Comment: @ВасилийПупкин Спасибо здесь принимает вид принятого ответа :) - с помощью птички слева...